# Tracking referrals with HasOffers - Not able to track Mobile app installed on android device via Desktop Browser

Tags: android, mobile, ads

Im trying to figure out a way to track Mobile app install via Google Play from desktop browser ( Desktop to Mobile install). However, Im not able to generate a post back to HasOffers servers once the install is successful on the mobile device. Has anyone else come across this issue ? Is this a limitation on the Google Play Platform ? Seems like trying to install from Desktop to a mobile device would be a common case in the Ads space. Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

thanks

-Sol

Answer (score 1):

it's a limitation of `HasOffers`.  Take a look at [Kochava](http://www.kochava.com) (www.kochava.com)

Comment: Thanks John. I was checking the Kochava support docs (http://support.kochava.com/customer/portal/articles/1153115-interested-in-integrating-as-a-network-publisher-with-kochava-) and I don't see any mention of desktop-to-mobile install. Have you been successful with it ? Thanks again.